# Catenated Email Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using js/jquery to check for the valid format of a string that can contain one to five comma-separated email addresses. I have only one case that is passing that should not pass when using the below methods:

```
    function isValidEmails(concatenatedEmails)
    {
        var compressedEmails = concatenatedEmails.replace(/ /g,'');
        var emails = compressedEmails.split(',');
        var isValid = true;
        if(emails.length > 0 && emails.length <= 5)
        {
            $.each(emails, function(index, email)
            {
                if(!isValidEmailFormat(email))
                {
                    isValid = false;
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            isValid = false;
        }
        return isValid;
    }

    function isValidEmailFormat(email)
    {
        return email.match("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                    + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
    }
```

These methods catch everything except a string that is passed in such as this:

```
"e1@mail.com, e2@mail.com, e3@mail.com, asdf"
```

This catches everything else, but somehow this string would make it through the validation. Could someone shed some light on how I can make this more efficient? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually ran fine for me . . . it returned `false`, when the "asdf" value was in there and `true` when I removed that value from the list.  Have you tried logging values to the console to see where things might be breaking for you?

---

As for code efficiency, for the most part, your code looks good.  There are only a couple of things that I could see that you could do to trim it down a little:

1. In the section of the `each()` where you check the validity of the email, if you `return` the value, when it is false, it will stop processing the rest of the emails (after all, there is no point in continuing to check them, after one is bad).  It's a small change:

   ```
   if(!isValidEmailFormat(email)) {
       return (isValid = false);
   }
   ```

   That will stop the loop the first time that it hits an invalid `email` value and move on to the `return` for the entire function.
2. You can also make your regex a little less complicated by using and actual `RegExp` value instead of a string) and adding the `i` flag, to make the pattern case insensitive.

   ```
   function isValidEmailFormat(email) {
       return email.match(/^[a-z0-9+_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$/i);
   }
   ```

   That lets you remove all of the instances of `A-Z` and removes the need to use double slashes (`\\`).  Also, `+` does not need to be escaped inside a character group, so I removed that.

Other than those two things, your code looks pretty good.

Comment: I appreciate your input. Thanks for the examples to make the code more efficient.